# How can I configure preseed to use a drive ONLY if it exists?

Tags: partitioning, preseed

Some of the machines that I'm provisioning have a separate `/dev/sdb` to be used for `/home`, and some only have a single disk.

Is there a way I can set up preseed so that if `/dev/sdb` exists, it uses 100% of that for `/home`, but if it doesn't, it makes a `/home` partition on `/dev/sda`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: as far as I am aware, you will need to run some kind of `early_command` to read the current disks and echo the results of that to a file that `partman` will read later, presumably on /hd-media somewhere.

I have once found a program/script that would do this, I think, but my Google-fu does not seem to work right now =/

Comment: Thanks. What I ended up doing was writing a little script for my postinstall which, if the 2nd disk is present, moves the contents of /home to that disk and then does all the necessary stuff (fstab, etc) to make that the new /home.